How to detect if there was any activity for a particular namespace in k8s cluster
In our Kubernetes cluster, we manage multiple namespaces. Our focus is on optimizing the cost of running the cluster. By identifying idle namespaces, we can potentially reduce costs significantly. This process of potential deletion is a key step in our cost-saving strategy.
Explored events at the cluster level but had limited information that was not helpful.Also tried with age of pods , but that also does not seem to be a very optimal way of addressing this. Any alternate suggestion. Thanks in advance.

The easiest way to monitor your namespace is via the portal under the namespace tab on the left side-

Now if you want to go deeper into each namespace and figure out stuffs like resource utilization, events and workloads then you can click on any of the namespace you created, and there you can see these stuffs

Second option to monitor namespace is via the inbuilt grafana dashboard which you can enable while setting up your cluster

You can play around with options or configure it as per your requirement

Then there is kubernetes own Kubernetes dashboard which is also very useful if you are not on AKS
AKS also offers similar dashboard like kubernetes dashboard under it's monitoring section called insights. Here you can filter out your namespace and monitor different parameters

Apart from this, basic things from cli level is also there like-
kubectl top pod -n <namespace-name>
kubectl get events -n <namespace-name>

Multiple ways are there to identify what resources are adding up to your cost. As shown above, filter out with your namespace and go ahead.
You can even go ahead and create a log analytics workspace and connect it to your AKS cluster and get different data from your namespace


if you have linked it to your aks cluster then you don't even have to go to your loganalytics dashboard seperately, it will reflect under log section of the monitoring tab in your aks cluster on the left.
References:

Kubernetes events for troubleshooting

